# Is it possible to see which IP addresses are using your Google API key?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have trawled all the way through GCP, GCP FAQ, GS & SO.  Would anyone know if it is possible to get the IP address information from Google API key requests?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t obtain any parameters in the return from Google’s service, the responses are pretty much set in stone and the only modifiers are whatever parameters you pass, BUT you could include a custom script to trigger along the request with the remote host’s IP address and use a web service like http://ip-api.com to decode the IP and store it along your request, this way you can correlate the created time of the Google API execution with the data you captured using a “ride along” script; just an idea if there’s any other way I’d love to know myself but I’ve used nearly all of Google’s APIs to know API analytics doesn’t show the requests origin IP nor does it store it anywhere, that’s why I’m suggesting implement a small bridge-through call to a third party service to get the data you need. :)

Comment: I guess Google has to draw the line for 'how much info do we store in a metrics object'...  I was hoping it would at least include the properties relating to key-usage restrictions...

Comment: They only care to measure that there was a consumption so they can hold it against your allotted quota and bill properly; client side data is never stored or returned (returned user data is only applicable when a user authorized your scope request when it comes to account related services); the solution is easy though just implement a third-party call to a service to properly track specific actions (similar to Analytics)

Comment: Thanks Ilan P, it makes perfect sense, I'll get started on your solution.  Have a great day!